# java JDBC ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException when delete, update

Tags: java, sql-server, swing, jdbc, indexoutofboundsexception

So i try to create a JTable which connect to SQL server database by JBDC, and have a function like insert, delete, and edit the data. It work well with insert but update, delete. Can you guys show me why i got `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1` and how to fix it. Here 's my code. Book here is a class extends JFRAME

```
public Book() {
    initComponents();

    model.addColumn("ID");
    model.addColumn("Name");
    model.addColumn("Type");

    jTable1.setModel(model);
    displayTable();
    jTable1.getSelectionModel().addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener() {
        @Override
        public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
            int row = jTable1.getSelectedRow();

            txtName.setText(jTable1.getValueAt(row, 1).toString());
            txtType.setText(jTable1.getValueAt(row, 2).toString());

        }
    });

}

public void displayTable() {
    try {
        model.setRowCount(0);
        ConnectToSQL sql = new ConnectToSQL();
        connection = sql.getConnection();
        st = connection.createStatement();
        ResultSet result = st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM BOOK");
        while (result.next()) {
            model.addRow(new Object[]{result.getInt("id"), result.getString("name"), result.getString("type")});
        }

    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Book.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}

private void btnUpdateActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    int row = jTable1.getSelectedRow();
    String id = jTable1.getValueAt(row, 0).toString();
    try {
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        st.executeUpdate("Update Book set name ='" + txtName.getText() + "',type='" + txtType.getText() + "' where id =" + id);
        displayTable();

    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Book.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

}

private void btnDeleteActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    int row = jTable1.getSelectedRow();
    String id = jTable1.getValueAt(row, 0).toString();
    try {
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        st.executeUpdate("Delete from book where id =" + id);
        displayTable();

    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Book.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

}
```

Comment: in which line ?you get this error

Comment: in btnUpdateActionPerformed and  btnDeleteActionPerformed i got ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException even though it still delete or update to database

Comment: well `-1` this happen when you do not select a row., and then selected row return `-1`.for example if `row=-1` then `jTable1.getValueAt(-1, 1)` and then you get the error.  To avoid it you can check `if(row!=-1){//do something}else{//plz select a row}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get this error, because you don't select any row, so to avoid this problem you have to use :

```
if(jTable1.getSelectedRow() != -1){
   int row = jTable1.getSelectedRow();
   String id = jTable1.getValueAt(row, 0).toString();
   //rest of your code here
}else{
   //show an error for example, no row is selected
}
```

---

**Note**

Instead of :

```
st.executeUpdate("Update Book set name ='" + txtName.getText() + "',type='" + txtType.getText() + "' where id =" + id);
```

You have to use PreparedStatement to avoid any syntax error or SQL Injection

For example :

```
String query = "Update Book set name = ?, type=? where id =?";

try (PreparedStatement update = connection.prepareStatement(query)) {

    update.setString(1, txtName.getText());
    update.setString(2, txtType.getText());
    update.setInt(3, id);

    update.executeUpdate();
}
```

Another thing, your id is an `int` so you can't set a String to your query like you do you have to set an int :

```
String id = jTable1.getValueAt(row, 0).toString();
```

Instead you have to use :

```
int id = Integer.parseInt(jTable1.getValueAt(row, 0).toString());
```

Comment: i tried to fix like you said but it stil got the exception, it get exception when ever i try to update the jtable after delete or edit data by displayTable() function

Comment: @TúAnhDư the `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` is gone or not?, what the new exception no?

Comment: it still ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1, i think it's  not getselectedRow() thing cause the exception because database updated after that but it come from the displayTable()

Comment: @TúAnhDư ok can you please debug your program and check where exactly your exception happen?

Comment: it come form displayTable()

Comment: @TúAnhDư can you try to empty your Table using this way : `DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel)table.getModel();
while(model.getRowCount() > 0)
{
    model.removeRow(0);
}` instead of `model.setRowCount(0);`

Comment: still got that exception =. =, if i delete all that commands to delete all rows and it work but duplicate value

Comment: @TúAnhDư can you use `catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }` and show me all the error?

Comment: can i give my all project to your email, i 'm newbie so i don't know how to use printStackTrace

Comment: @TúAnhDư replace `Logger.getLogger(Book.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);` with `e.printStackTrace();` in your `displayTable` method thats all

Comment: Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
 at java.util.Vector.elementData(Vector.java:734)
 at java.util.Vector.elementAt(Vector.java:477)
 at javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel.getValueAt(DefaultTableModel.java:648)
 at javax.swing.JTable.getValueAt(JTable.java:2717)
 at jdbc.Book$1.valueChanged(Book.java:51)
 at javax.swing.DefaultListSelectionModel.fireValueChanged(DefaultListSelectionModel.java:184)

Comment: @TúAnhDư can you show us how you initialize `model`?

Comment: model = (DefaultTableModel)jTable1.getModel();
          model.addColumn("ID");
            model.addColumn("Name");
            model.addColumn("Type");
            jTable1.setModel(model);
             
             displayTable();

Comment: txtName.setText(jTable1.getValueAt(row,1).toString());

Comment: @TúAnhDư so your error is not in your display method, ok can you comment `jTable1.getSelectionModel().addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener() {
        @Override
        public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
            int row = jTable1.getSelectedRow();

            txtName.setText(jTable1.getValueAt(row, 1).toString());
            txtType.setText(jTable1.getValueAt(row, 2).toString());

        }
    });` and try again?

Comment: wow it works, i change addListSelectionListener to jTableMouseClick and it work pertfectly, but i don't know why that did't work... anyway thanks you so muck for spending your time help me